# Why is traversal forward only most of the time?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, iterator, traversal

I have noticed that many iterators or data readers are forward only like [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx), [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx), any many more *(you got the idea)*.

So simply asking why are they **forward-only** usually when i create a Data Iterator for my custom needs i usually Try adding support for navigation on both sides. I agree that most of time we don't need backward traversing but sometimes we do need and so we end up creating `temp` variables or something to hold on the data while required.

---

So my questions are:

- Why are most Data-Iterators forward-only
- **Am i wrong** in creating a backward traversable Iterator/ Data reader. if not why doesn't framework have such support for its inbuilt Data Iterators.
- Do we have any ***serious*** performance drawback or its just **not** considered a **good design** to have such feature.

---

*This question has bugged me a lot from start but never got a satisfactory answer so I'm asking it here.I do believe many developers may agree with me that backward traversing can be useful sometimes.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"forwards only" is:

- the most common use for most consumers
- simple to implement, so the most likely to *be* implemented by most producers
- the only thing we can guaranteed if we assume we don't want to buffer all the data in memory
- easily buffered to allow random access (for moderate sized data)

for example, if you are reading data from a database, a network stream, etc, you can only guarantee "forwards".  We certainly don't want to arbitrarily buffer all that data - it could be **huge** potentially.

If the client thinks they have a sane amount of data, they can always call `ToList()` etc to buffer it in memory and allow random access.

For example, consider this **perfectly valid** sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> LotsOfData() {
    var random = new Random();
    while(true) yield return random.Next();
}
```

- it can't be reversed without buffering
- it is infinite in length, so can't be buffered

obviously that example is a little unlikely, but reading from a socket, database, or even a large file - can be *essentially* the same scenario.

Comment: you are definitely right in that scenario but while reading data from even a large file what can be problem if we read a little backward.. the logic will be like to move the pointer some counter back in bits and read again.. of course we will need to write a little more code.. so what could go wrong in this design?

Comment: Well the idea is to have one generic base approach that works for (basically) everything. Nothing is preventing you from having other access schemes in special scenarios (like backward reading or random access)

Comment: Basic SRP :). Don't add non essential functionality to objects. Also - I like bullet 4. It's easy to add buffering if you need it.

Comment: @Shekhar - the problem there is that it limits te caller to seekable streams. If you only need a *little* way back, then there are ways to handle that, obviously - like perhaps a circular buffer.